# Heroku update files inside it every 24h

Tags: python, heroku, bots, discord

Heroku restarts every 24 hours, is there any way I can program it to not do this, or update my files that are inside it every 23h or 24h?
I use python, and use heroku to host my discord bot.

Comment: Well, you could pay for a proper plan, then it workshy restart quite do often. But why do you care if it restarts?

Comment: well, I have several json files in heroku, and this reboot returns the json files to the original, and does not save the new ones, so I need a way to update my files in a given time

Comment: This is a sign that your architecture is wrong. You *cannot* store files on the Heroku file system, and the docs are absolutely clear on this point (eg [here](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)). Put the data in a database, or store the files somewhere permanent like S3.

Answer (score 2):

The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted.

If you are looking to work with PaaS (Platform as a Service) you must to change your application design and your mine.

[Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)

[12 FACTOR](https://12factor.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't store information on Heroku file system,
you need to store your data in some database, for example, Postgres or MongoDB.
The can be added easily as an addon on Resources tab.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials or videos that I can follow in order to host my files in Postgres or MongoDB?

Comment: You don't need to host files in Database. Only some data you need to keep if the server will restart. Just search:

    <programming language> + <your framework name> + <database name>

And you'll get a lot of videos and tutorials about that.